# New Tag proposal: analysis

Tags: discussion, tags

I am currently taking two analysis courses at my university right now, and will likely be taking some form of analysis for the next two semesters as well so I thought I would try my hand at some analysis code golf questions.  However when I searched [`[analysis]`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) I came up with no results because the tag does not exist.

Should we have an [analysis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag?  If so what kind of questions would fall under "analysis"?  If we decide on some criteria are there any existing questions that should be tagged with [analysis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis)?

Comment: The only way to create a tag is to apply to a question/challenge.

Comment: For reference, see Math.SE's tag: [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info)

Comment: Math and Numeric tags are enough... Possible a tag for <cas> computer algebra sys...

Answer (score 2):

### Maybe, but definitely not with that name

One problem which pretty much every StackExchange site has is mistagging due to people starting to type a tag and selecting something from the autocomplete without reading (or maybe just without understanding) the short description. The word *analysis* has a general English meaning which is far broader than the technical meaning it has acquired in mathematics, so creating a tag [analysis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) for the mathematical field would result in it being used wrongly more often than it's used correctly.

Even [mathematical-analysis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-analysis) risks being overapplied. It may be better to use more specific tags for subfields (e.g. [calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) already exists) and then to mention the other subfields under a "Related tags" section in the tag wiki so that people who want to add them to favourite tags can.

Comment: Maybe [tag:numerical-analysis]?

Comment: @mbomb007, that's a subfield.

Comment: What's an example of something not contained within that field?

Comment: @mbomb007, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_analysis#Main_branches

Comment: Yeah, [tag:mathematical-analysis] is probably the best we can do. Otherwise, just copy the tag from Math.SE: [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info).

Comment: @mbomb007, on math.SE there's a reasonable expectation that users will be mathematicians. That's not a reasonable expectation here. (And even so, math.meta.SE has a few threads about repeated problems with certain tags being misused).

Answer (score -1):

## Yes, we should have [analysis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis)

I may have tipped my hand in asking this question, but I think it would be a good idea.  These questions might not be the easiest tag for programming challenges because they often deal with the infinite, but there are still plenty of interesting and unique challenges that could be asked.

Here is a mock up of what the tag description/wiki might look like:

### Description:

---

Analysis is the study of limits, convergence, and related concepts such as differentiation and continuity.

---

### Wiki:

---

This tag is for questions that explore the topics of [Mathematical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_analysis).  Analysis has a number of subfields pertaining to more specific topics.

### [Real analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/real-analysis/info)

Real analysis is the branch of analysis that is concerned with functions on the [Real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number).  It includes topics such as [convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_(mathematics)), [continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function), [metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) and [smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_function)

### [Complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/complex-analysis/info)

Complex analysis is concerned with functions of complex variables. Complex analysis is concerned with the extension of the ideas of real analysis into the complex plane. Important topics in Complex analysis include analyticity, branch cuts and residues.  Questions about complex numbers but not specifically about analysis should be tagged with [complex-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers).

[analysis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) should be used for topics in these areas as well

---

I have made this community wiki so anyone may help me complete it as they see fit.  I am not very familiar with functional analysis so if someone would like to add a bit about that I would be pleased.